# Controller syntax error and database issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, controller

I am building a database and am getting issues with the controller corresponding with the list, show, new, ect. actions.  This is my controller code:

```
class SkillsController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @skills = Skill.all
   end

   def show
    @skills = Skill.find(params[:id])
   end

   def new
    @skills = Skill.all

   end

   def create
        @skills = Skill.new(params[:skill])
      if @skills.save
            redirect_to :action => 'list'
      else
            @skills = Skill.find(:all)
            render :action => 'new'
      end
   end

   def edit
    @skills = Skill.find(params[:id])
    @skills = Skill.find(:all)
   end

   def update
       @skills = Skill.find(params[:id])
      if @skills.update_attributes(params[:skill])
         redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @skills
      else
         @skills = Skill.find(:all)
         render :action => 'edit'
      end
   end

   def delete
    Skill.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to :action => 'list'
   end

     def show_skills
      @skills = Skill.find(params[:id])
   end
end
```

My error when I try and go to localhost:3000:skills/list is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SkillsController#show
Couldn't find Skill with 'id'=list
```

and this line of code is highlighted as the problem area:

```
        @skills = Skill.find(params[:id])
```

I am guessing that my skills are not correctly built to have ID's but I am not sure and I read that was generated automatically without declaring tables will have id's.  Thank you to anyone who knows what my issue is and I hope it is a simple syntax error.  Cheers and thanks again.

I tried changing it to Skill.all and now I am getting a missing template error.  It is not looking in my views/skills dir to find the templates and I do not know why.  If anyone also has any advice on this It would be much appreciated.  Thanks again and best of luck! 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^solved^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

This is the list.rhtml view:

```
<% if @skills.blank? %>
  <p>There are not any skills currently saved in the system.</p>
<% else %>
  <p>These are the current skills saved in our system</p>
  <ul id="skills">
    <% @skills.each do |c| %>
      <li><%= link_to c.title, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} -%></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>

<p><%= link_to "Add new Skill", {:action => 'new' }%></p>    

<li>
      <%= link_to c.title, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} -%>
  <b> <%= link_to 'Edit', {:action => 'edit', :id => c.id} %></b>
  <b> <%= link_to "Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => c.id},
                             :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this skill??" %></b>
</li>
```

I figured out the controller issue and am now only having an issue with the view above.  The error is:

```
 /app/views/skills/index.html.erb where line #16 raised:

undefined local variable or method `c' for #<#<Class:0x000000055b1620>:0x0000000413d338>
```

and the specific line it is pointing to is:

```
 <%= link_to c.title, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} -%>
```

I think the c.id is an invalid param for my database but I am not sure.  I will keep trying to fix it and thanks anyone who knows anything.

Comment: yes posting it now above.

Comment: So, you'd either need to rename this view to be `show.rhtml` or follow @PeterSorowka's solution.  The missing template is because the action `show` is looking for `show` template, it doesn't know about `list.rhtml`.

Comment: I see! thank you, I will keep at it and try and fix it.

Comment: I changed the list.rhtml to show.rhtml and am still getting this error::::Template is missing
Missing template skills/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/HandCoOp/project/HandCoOp/app/views" * "C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/views"

Comment: Your ruby and rails gems suggests that you are definitely using Rails 3+.  Why do you have `rhtml` extension?  Try changing that file extension to `.html.erb`.  Is this an old project brought up from Rails 2?

Comment: I was following a tutorial! must be old and I was wondering why it was rhtml! thanks I will try.

Comment: It is good practice on StackOverflow to only ask one question at once and when this is solved and you have follow-up problems, open a new question. This is for the sake of a clean problem->solution structure on the platform. Your error is very simple to solve, you are refering to the variable `c` which you had defined earlier in the `@skills.each` block. The last four lines are, however, outside of the block, which is why the variable is not available anymore. The `<li>` is also not in a `<ul>` context, so you obviously mixed some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive the error message, because you did not (or not correctly) set up a route for the `list` action. Currently rails routes you mistakingly to the `show` action for an element with an ID of 'list' which obviously does not exist.

The rails default name for the `list` action is `index` and the default route for that would be just localhost:3000/skills/ If you want to go that path, you do not have to change anything except the method name in the controller.

If you want to use the path localhost:3000/skills/list to call the method `list` in your controller, you have to change your `config/routes.rb` file to contain

```
resources :skills do 
  get 'list'
end
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, I am getting a new error for the index.html.erb but I will add the error below the index.html.erb above.